# Steam Game Share Question

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

So my brother recently bought Rust and lets me use his Steam account to play it. Would there be a way for him to play CS:GO while I play Rust. Is there a way to do that with Steam Family Sharing?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Steam Family Sharing allows you to play a game from the shared library as long as only one of you is playing it (unless both of you have the game in your own libraries in which case that restriction has no effect).

Comment: Wrong. The "giving side"'s library is only available for sharing while they are not playing ANY game of their library. Whether or not it is the currently shared game does not matter.